# Is there a policy on plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, moderation, plagiarism, attribution

I recently saw an answer that was mostly copied from an existing answer to a different question, and thought to myself "ooh I should flag that".  But then I considered that this person was just trying to be helpful, even if they failed to do so using their own words and did not give credit to the author.

We often copy information into our answers, except usually it's cited and/or quoted.  A common example is including relevant sections of a language standard.

But this just feels odd.  Here's a screenshot of the answer, with the copied section highlighted.  Answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34915189/1553090)

[image: Plagiarised]

And this is part of the original which lives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/99010/1553090)

[image: Original]

When I see something like this, what action (if any) should be taken?  In this instance, I dropped a comment on the question pointing out that I noticed.  The user's response was to simply add a line link to the original as providing "a better explanation".

Comment: Read more at [How to reference](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) and the [MSE FAQ about how to deal with plagiarism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered)

Comment: To add some weight to Ed's answer here, in general, raising a custom flag and explaining the situation *is* very efficient; in the past I have seen these handled quickly and accurately.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

We do have a policy on plagiarism: it's not okay. We require full attribution with a link to the original author, and even then users may not copy content without permission. The permission issue isn't a problem when a user quotes a Stack Overflow post (as long as he or she doesn't copy the whole thing*), but we still require a link.

The best way to handle plagiarism when you see it is simply raise a custom moderator flag and say something like this:

> This answer was partially plagiarized from https://stackoverflow.com/a/99010/1553090 (starting at "The strict aliasing rule makes")

We can handle this in a number of ways, but only when you bring it to our attention. Of course, raising it on Meta also got moderator attention, but it's less efficient than a simple flag.

Thanks for pointing this out. I've gone ahead and cleaned up the offending post and left a comment informing the user how to handle quoting material in the future.

---

* Note: If a user copies the whole answer, even if it's his or her own answer, that's almost always a sign that (1) the question should be closed as a duplicate, (2) the user isn't paying attention, (3) the user is a spammer, or (4) some combination of the above. It's basically never okay to give *exactly* the same answer to two questions and not vote to close one of them.

Comment: It would have helped if I could spell "plagiari[s/z]e" too.  Glad that my question was edited.  But I just tried searching the help center for that word and there was still nothing in there.  So I don't feel too bad asking.  Using "attribution" as a search word is helpful, and got me to the blog post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Comment: Ha, no worries - this was a good question. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: Maybe, one should also leave a comment under the user's answer as well. So that more people would see it and know what they're supposed to do. (I used to do this, when I didn't know any better :(

Comment: I'm glad that this question happened to be asked  because I've been wondering about a similar problem today (user self-answering [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34916540/5015207) by linking to another user's answer and copy-pasting the relevant code) I had already flagged the answer as VLQ but OP was not impressed :( So I should flag the question as duplicate because OP feels the other answer is the perfect solution?

Comment: @0X0nosugar I'm not an Android developer, so I'm not personally sure whether it's a duplicate or not, but you are right that the copy-pasting of that answer didn't add anything. The new "answer" was pretty low-quality.

Comment: @EdCottrell - regarding a user copying their whole answer - is there any guidance when the original answer is on another SE site? For example, I have in the past copied significant portions of one of my answers on SuperUser to a similar question on SO. The question was on-topic on both sites.

Comment: @MattDMo The guidance is pretty much the same: feel free to use that material as long as you provide a link and as long as you make the answer specifically relevant to the question. In practical terms, there's a little more flexibility with posts quoting other SE sites because we can't close a question on SO as a dupe of a question on SU or another site. But in general, you'll still want to add a little context, tweak the material as needed, and so on.

Comment: And...the owner deleted his post.

Comment: @JonH Oh well. Fortunately, paddy included screenshots in the question (and, obviously, 10k users can still see it anyway).