# What do we do if someone has copied the code from one's answer for their own answer

Tags: discussion, specific-question, plagiarism

I have posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943302/how-to-use-jump-to-a-specific-div-of-current-page-in-codeigniter/34944914#34944914). I was the first to do so and then I noticed this morning some other user after me has copied my welcome controller code and then his answer got [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943302/how-to-use-jump-to-a-specific-div-of-current-page-in-codeigniter/34946630#34946630) on the same question.  A bit unfair I think.

What do you do?

**Update:** The copied answer has now been removed.

Comment: If you suspect plagarism, you can flag "In need of moderator attention" and explain what's going on. Be sure to link to the original source that parts of the answer were taken from, even if it's on the same page.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315162/is-there-a-policy-on-plagiarism

Comment: Update: The copied answer has now been removed.