# How should I handle copy/paste from another SE site?

Tags: discussion, answers, plagiarism

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69097834/it-it-possible-to-have-private-files-in-a-public-repository) and got [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69097937/903011). While browsing comments, I found out that the answer is an *exact* copy/paste of another answer, **from another SE site (Super User)** - *without any credit*.

I commented that this is a bad thing to do and flagged the answer.

Now I wonder what to do with that. The answer, while not extraordinary, has the merit of existing. Cross-linking in SE is not possible, but I still would like to point to that answer (even if there are more on the way).

Several possibilities I can think of:

- give up and hope that the comments are enough to guide someone
- edit the answer with the plagiarism to make it a quote with proper sourcing
- make a new answer and quote/source the SU one.

Since the original is posted on another SE site I cannot close it as a duplicate.

Comment: Much better duplicate target: [How do we deal with plagiarized answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268629/11682469) (also: [Is there a policy on plagiarism?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315162/11682469)

Comment: @JeanneDark: this is a very good reference link, but my problem is about how to keep a reference to that other answer. I already flagged the answer, but what will probably happen is that t will be deleted.

Comment: Probably just mod flag the plagiarism (include link to original answer) and then you might consider providing your own answer with proper attribution (and if you don't feel like deserving rep for it, you could make it community wiki).

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName: this answer is about a duplicate on the same site (where you can close it as duplicate).

Comment: @RobertLongson: the link was already mentioned in an earlier comment

Comment: That is a system auto comment created when voting to close.

Comment: The generic guideline is "don't flag if you can fix it". You definitely *could* go for option 2. But this seems to be a clear exception to that guideline, it is a case where the perpetrator should not be let off without at least a warning. So option #2 is not ideal.

Comment: OK, so the question was closed with two duplicates which are not duplicates... Anyway, I created a wiki answer for the question in my specific case.