# Shouldn't we have a copied content without attribution flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, attribution

I found an answer which is a composite verbatim copy of content found in:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-data-types/ and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/derived-data-types-in-c/ as well as some subpages.

I did leave a comment on the answer and will wait for user feedback before flagging it.

The question is, there is no flag that directly addresses this, besides moderator intervention, that is:

[image]

This happens often enough, especially for new users, to make me wonder if we should have a ***copied content without attribution flag*** (or something similar) so we don't have to flag moderator intervention every time this happens. We'd have to have a textbox to post the sources, of course.

I understand that this is a serious matter, and can be more serious if the user repeats the behavior, but it seems that the *mods* normally don't go through all the user's posts to see if there are more instances of the offense, that would be a lot of work.

So my idea is that a flag like this could be valuable to identify first offenders, and, if the user has more flags of this type, then a moderator intervention can be prompted.

I don't think this would be very hard to implement and the main advantage would be to relieve the mod flag queues, *normal* reviewers  can easily evaluate if a post needs attribution. It can also help streamline the process of identifying serial plagiarists [as pointed out in the comment section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412703/shouldnt-we-have-a-copied-content-without-attribution-flag#comment877097_412703).

Is this something that can make sense?

Comment: I would agree with you. But how or who will handle this specific category of flags (You would need to also submit link to original content) if not a moderator?

Comment: Related meta discussions: [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/478746) and [Is there a policy on plagiarism?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315162/11082165),

Comment: There is a flag for it, it's the "In need for moderator attention" flag. A flag that says the post is plagiarism on its own isn't helpful; there's no link to the original source or additional information. Any curators or moderator would have to redo the investigative work you did. With a custom flag you can include all the info and the mod can action accordingly.

Comment: Why do you feel that an "in need of moderator intervention" flag doesn't work or isn't sufficient for these issues? What benefit are you expecting to get from having a specific flag? I agree there are potential benefits with more structure and potentially specific tooling for these, at least from a moderator's perspective, particularly better tooling for evaluating them, but I'm wondering what you see as the benefit from a user's perspective? From a user's perspective, it doesn't seem like raising a custom mod-flag with "Plagiarized from [link]" is all that onerous.

Comment: @Larnu That's something which should be dealt with using flags, not on MSO. Other than raise flags, the appropriate response isn't to raise a posse of users on MSO to downvote and delete-vote a user's posts. We do want users flagging plagiarism. We just don't want users giving the typical meta response to such actions, which often includes serial voting.

Comment: I had raised a flag, @Makyen . My point is it doesn't appear to be a one off and I don't have time, currently to check more posts

Comment: @Larnu I'm aware of that, but if you did or didn't flag a post is not something for me to share publicly unless you bring it up.

Comment: Then why ask me to flag when you could see I had, @Makyen ?

Comment: I didn't. I explained that posting on MSO wasn't the place to address what you were commenting about. My comment was intentionally made without indicating if there were any existing flags from you or anyone else in order to preserve the privacy of anyone who may have raised a flag.

Comment: So it is ok for me to say what I said if I was transparent about my flag, @Makyen? I'm not following you here.

Comment: @Makyen I see you removed the link, is there anything wrong with posting links to problematic questions?

Comment: @anastaciu „I don't think is plagiarism, it's just lack of attribution“ is there a difference?

Comment: *"it's not plagiarism, it's just lack of attribution, "* that is [plagiarism](https://www.ox.ac.uk/students/academic/guidance/skills/plagiarism): "Plagiarism is presenting someone else's work or ideas as your own, with or without their consent, by incorporating it into your work without full acknowledgement." The OP has posted an answer, which is expressed as their own content (as it's not in a blockquote) but the content is someone else's work and  it has been provided without acknowledgement.

Comment: @anastaciu Having the link already resulted in another user going through the linked answer's author's other posts looking for other plagiarism and then posting here about it. While we do want people to find and flag plagiarism, we don't want a swarm of meta users serially downvoting a user, which is what tends to happen when something's posted on MSO in a way that draws negative attention. It didn't appear that linking to the specific example answer you originally provided provided much benefit to your question, as your question isn't about the specific question. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Makyen with respect, users that plagiarise here tend to do it repeatedly. And, though I can not speak for others, the "other user" you likely speak of (me) didn't downvote. My experience has been that when I find a user that has [plagiarised], if I don't check other answers and flag them, those other answers aren't dealt with. I'm not condoning mass downvotes (this is why I **haven't** down voted) but it feels off with me that were hiding the user.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, though you're right, I think intention matters, maybe the OP isn't aware they must post the sources, I think we should be more lenient with a first offense, if that is the case.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, unfortunately, users who plagiarize tend to do so more than once, sometimes in hundreds of posts. We appreciate you and other users finding plagiarism and flagging it, as raising a flag with a link to the source dramatically reduces the amount of time we have to spend when handling a flag. A user's posts *do* take a lot of time to go through looking for plagiarism. Going through the rest of a user's posts looking for plagiarism, or, at least, a significant chunk of them, is something that takes a *lot* of time when handling plagiarism flags.

Comment: @Larnu I didn't mean to imply that *you* downvoted. I don't know, and can't tell, who downvoted that answer. I can tell that the answer which was linked here was downvoted twice since this question was posted, and, historically, people *tend* to end up serially downvoting users who are negatively brought to the attention of MSO. I edited the question and deleted a comment here in an effort to make it less likely that the user would end up serially downvoted (which, when it happens, is just another mess the moderators and the CMs have to clean up).

Comment: Based on the comments made by Cody in the recent events with Shree, @anastaciu , it can be assumed (in my opinion) that the mods are more leniant on first offences.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for clarifying, @Makyen . Seems like intention on comments was missed a bit here; apologies if I seemed I was being awkward.

Comment: @Larnu, yes, fortunately, I won't use that word unless I absolutely have to, because it's very heavily charged.

Comment: A good idea. I recognise some may consider this flag _too specific_ but it would quickly become a useful marker / metric for identifying serial plagiarists.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> There is a flag for it, it's the "In need for moderator attention" flag. A flag that says the post is plagiarism on its own isn't helpful; there's no link to the original source or additional information. Any curators or moderator would have to redo the investigative work you did. With a custom flag you can include all the info and the mod can action accordingly.

*-- [comment](/q/412703/#comment876556_412703) by [Larnu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu)*

This mirrors the advice in the Meta SE FAQ, [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/343832):

> ### 2. Edit or flag
>
> If it looks like a **minor, single incident**, editing the attribution in is the way to go. [...]
>
> If it looks like there is an **egregious pattern of plagiarism,** and deletions seem necessary, flag for moderator attention.  Explain  that you believe the answer has been plagiarized, and paste the source URL into a comment underneath, say `Plagiarism: copied without attribution from ....`

> ### 4. Go hunt for more
>
> Moderators have enough to do already - they won't be able to check out a user's entire profile for further instances of plagiarism. If you feel like it, take that task upon yourself, and flag each occurrence as described above.

Comment: *"If it looks like a minor, single incident, editing the attribution in is the way to go. [...]"* This seems nice to me, but I've experienced a similar situation, an attibution was added to the answer and some time later a mod deleted the answer with a comment similar to "*Retro attribution won't prevent deletion*", so there are some mixed signals here.

Comment: I think it really depends on *how8 you did it, @anastaciu . I don't know what the original answer you speak about was, but I suspect that if you put the content that wasn't yours in quoteblocks and just didn't cite the source, I suspect that deletion might have been avoided; it's still plagarism but you at least demonstrate the words aren't yours. It's when people both don't cite and don't put the [other person's] content in quoteblocks that is a real problem (though not citing is still bad, don't mistake me for saying it isn't); it makes it look like the post is wholly written by them.

Comment: @Larnu, It was the latter, there was no quotation nor attribution, so it's consistent with what you describe.

Comment: A minor incident would be where someone openly states that it's a solution taken from elsewhere without naming the source correctly (wrong URL, failing to add quote formatting and similar). Otherwise, if they post it as if it was their own content with no attribution, it is not minor.